# Epic Maneuvers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat-maneuver

So, the Book of Nine Swords gives us the opportunity to become the %race% of steel and pure awesomeness, it gives us maneuvers that make the character into one-man-army and stuff, and that's really great. However, there is one thing that keeps bothering me

I found NO maneuvers for epic martial adepts-at least, as far as I looked. There are no epic maneuvers for 20+ levels in the existing 9 schools, nor there are any additional schools to get that swordsage something equal to 10th level spells.

So, the question is-where can one find anything about "what to do next"? If some swordsage just creates his own 10th level maneuvers like a mage would do, the fact that he can perform it repeatedly and after he ran out of his maneuvers he can replenish them with just one turn of being passive, it kind of breaks the balance-so, I guess, there should be something else, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been no official epic level supplement to the Book of Nine Swords. A [thread on the subject](http://www.enworld.org/forum/d-d-legacy-discussion/194898-epic-book-nine-swords.html) was posted at enworld in 2007 and generated no interest or results.

Comment: Oh, snaps.I thought that maybe, just maybe, there was something in Dragon Magazine or similiar resource and I just missed it... Well, I guess I'll just either expand the nine schools with some epic stuff, or make an epic martial school, or something. Anyway, thanks 8)

Answer (score 4):

### There's Homebrew For That

Here, have a list.

- TheDementedOne creates a [rules framework](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?134459-Epic-Martial-Discipline-Invincible-Sword-Princess) for Epic Disciplines, based loosely on Epic Magic.  Included is the Epic discipline, [Invincible Sword Princess](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=7468745&postcount=2).
- [March of Aeons](http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php?topic=775.0), by Bozwevial, whose entry feat is Knight of Paradox which should tell you everything you need to know about that.
- [Nine-Petaled Lotus](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?263389-The-Tenth-Discipline-the-Nine-Petaled-Lotus-Epic-ToB), by Jarian, which is the Master of Nine gone Epic.
- [Celestial Impetus](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?267881-Celestial-Impetus-%28Epic-Martial-Discipline%29), by sirpercival, one man's love affair with the [Force] descriptor.
- [Seven Forged Sword](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=8834.0), by sirpercival again, which is a different love affair with Prismatic effects.  And shooting them everywhere.
- [Devouring Crypt](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=8822.0), by the same, be a lich but better, and make the living fear your scythe.
- [Primeval God-Monster](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?250965-3-5-Epic-Discipline-Primeval-God-Monster), by Xefas, the Epic version of the Infernal Monster homebrew discipline.  Grow arms, be angry, kill things all the time forever.
- [Epic Martial Adept Progressions](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?95516-Epic-Martial-Adept-Progressions-and-Feats) (Crusader, Swordsage, Warblade) and Epic martial adept feats by Krimm_Blackleaf.
- [The 9 Epic Martial Discipline Feats](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?95435-9-Martial-Discipline-Epic-Feats), by Krimm_Blackleaf

Additionally, there are some regular homebrew disciplines that are head and shoulders above the rest, so here you are.

- [Black Rain](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?99529-The-Sublime-Gunslinger-s-Art-Black-Rain-Discipline), the Sublime Gunslinger's Art by TheDementedOne.
- [Kuji-Kiri](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?204787-Kuji-Kiri-Discipline-%28CV-Ninja-as-martial-discipline%29), some Ninja to go with your Darkness, by Chambers.
- [Dancing Leaf](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?85614-I-m-A-Leaf-On-The-Wind-Discipline), intensely flavourful for any dex-based combatant and just a beautiful meld of fluff and mechanics.  By TheDementedOne.
- [Lightning Fox](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?95435-9-Martial-Discipline-Epic-Feats), by Person_Man.  Also includes the Vanguard class.
- [Akasha's Timepiece](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?262577-3-5-Martial-Discipline-Akasha-s-Timepiece-College), by jiriku.
- [Scarlet Bravura](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?101008-Just-Who-The-Hell-Do-You-Think-We-Are!-Discipline&p=5569037#post5569037), by TheDementedOne.
- [Fool's Grip](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?67879-Fool-s-Grip-Discipline), by TheDementedOne.
- [Sleeping Goddess](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?98409-Sleeping-Goddess-Discipline&p=5408276#post5408276), by TheDementedOne.
- [Witch Razor](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?102869-Witch-Razor-Discipline), by pyrefiend.
- [Sublime Tapestry](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1351), by Garryl.
- [Hero's Edge](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?169940-We-reject-physics-in-the-name-of-AWESOME!-%28ToB-Discipline-repost-3-5-WIP%29), by The Mage King.
- [Revolution](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=7095.msg109053#msg109053), by sirpercival.

Sirpercival maintains a [Martial Discipline Compendium](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=6265.0) with all the known usable Disciplines homebrewed to date.

Source(s):  GitP, Minmaxboards, mmx, 339, Sirpercival's Martial Discipline compendium, I have used these in games.

Comment: There are a *lot* more homebrew disciplines than those, and a surprising number of them are high quality. I suspect the quality of the book (and the effort necessary to do a whole discipline) serve to encourage higher quality. Anyway, [sirpercival maintains a comprehensive list](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=6265.0) (comprehensive does mean there’s not necessarily quality control though, but most of them are pretty solid).

Comment: Having just parsed that list in creating a ToB character in a homebrew-approved game, I can say it is a hell of a chore.  Those are the ones that stuck out at me, so i've included them here.  I'll put a link into the actual answer to percy's compendium.  Only just realized this is 2 years old.

Comment: @JackLesnie The age of the question doesn't matter on this site. If you feel your answer adds something that existing answers don't, that's all that matters